# OpenCart SQL request and display on product template page

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to access an id a table to display on the product page on OpenCart 2.0.3.1.

I am trying to access an id from a table and then bring it into the product page and display it on the variant options on the drop-down.

I run the SQL for one product and get the id 21. so for debugging reasons I add the two variables (product_id and option_id) manually so those arent causing an issue. Below is a screenshot of the sql query working

[image]

So it returns with the number 21. Obviously when I change the sql to be the product_id and option_id for each product it will return the relevant id.

I have this setup:

**catalog/model/catalog/product.php**

```
public function getOtpOptionId($product_id)
{
    $otp_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT id from oc_otp_option_value where product_id = 62 AND parent_option_value_id = 20");
    $otp_option = $otp_option_query->row;
    return $otp_option;
}
```

**catalog/controller/product/product.php**

below

```
foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
```

I add

```
$data['otp_option_id'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getOtpOptionId($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

**catalog/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl**

I change:

```
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?></option>
```

to be

```
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?> (<?php echo $data['otp_option_id']; ?>)</option>
```

I would expect it to show all the options in the drop-down with (21)

for example:
red (21)
blue (21)
Green (21)

It just shows each option with no number and only the ().

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

/******* UPDATE *******/

So I have changed the code in the model to pick up the id of each option rather than using numbers

```
    public function getOtpOptionId($product_id, $option_value_id)
{
    $otp_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT id from oc_otp_option_value where product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND parent_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option_value_id . "'");
    $otp_option = $otp_option_query->row;
    return $otp_option;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use this code inside `foreach` loop later:

```
$data['otp_option_id'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getOtpOptionId($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

you should not put it inside the loop, you can place it after this code, that is outside the loop:

```
$data['options'] = array();
```

And in your view file, instead of:

```
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?> (<?php echo $data['otp_option_id']; ?>)</option>
```

Use:

```
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?> (<?php echo $otp_option_id; ?>)</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.It works! @DigitCart. however I need it in the loop as it will have a different product_id for each product. Can I do this?

Comment: You can see the code that I have changed above under /* UPDATE */ thanks

Comment: You're welcome. So you can use it inside loop. If my post solved your issue please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: When I put it inside the loop it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: do you know why it doesn't work when I have a variable in the loop. for example if I even put $data['otp_option_id'] = "yes"; it doesn't show the word yes?

Comment: Do you know how I can make it work in the foreach loop?